# 2010 Access - how to add and work with shapes in Excel file

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I would like to add shapes and modify them from 2010 Access vba in an Excel worksheet.

The code I wrote based on Excel 'record macro' is:

```
StrSheetName = "Menu"
wkbModels.Sheets.Add(before:=wkbModels.Sheets("Models")).Name = StrSheetName
Set wksModelsMenu = wkbModels.Sheets(StrSheetName)

With wksModelsMenu
    iLeft = 1
    iTop = 1
    iWidth = 125
    iHeight = 200
    .Shapes.AddPicture fDirectory & "logo.jpg", False, True, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight
    iLeft = 240
    iTop = 1
    iWidth = 300
    iHeight = 125
    .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight).Select
    .Shapes(1).Range.ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset10
    .Shapes(1).Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    .Shapes(1).Range.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    .Shapes(1).Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
                "TEST TEST TEST"
    .Shapes(1).Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    .Shapes(1).Range.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Bold = msoTrue
End With
```

On the ".Shapes(1).Range.ShapeStyle..." and following ".Shapes(1)." statements I receive an error "Object doesn't support this property or method".  Removing the "(1)" gives a compile error.

The mso library is installed and the referenced items (i.e., msoShapeStylePreset10) have the proper values.

Any ideas on what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for what it's worth, I found that if I moved the index from after the "Shapes" to after the "Range" it works as needed.

This:

```
Shapes(1).Range.....
```

changes to:

```
Shapes.Range(1)
```

Of course if you look at the code, you see that the second shape is what I really want to work on.

```
Shapes(2).Range
```

did not work.

```
Shapes.Range(2)
```

worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

`Shapes(1)` returns a `Shape` object, which does NOT have a `Range` member, so `Shapes(1).Range` will generate an error. Removing `Range` from each line will likely fix your problem, for example `Shapes(1).ShapeStyle = ...`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Worksheet.Shapes.AddShape()` returns a `Shape` object.

It is better to use this object, instead of relying on the created shape being the second one on the sheet (which may change at some point).

This code (without `.Range`) works for me in Access 2010:

```
Dim shp As Excel.Shape

' Note: there is no reason to select the shape
Set shp = wksModelsMenu.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight)
' Use the created object to set its properties
With shp
    .ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset10
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "TEST TEST TEST"
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Bold = msoTrue
End With
```

You can also do it without a Shape variable (but I find the above code better readable):

```
With wksModelsMenu.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight)
    .ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset10
    ' etc.
End With
```

---

Additional note:
You can do the same when creating the sheet:

```
Set wksModelsMenu = wkbModels.Sheets.Add(before:=wkbModels.Sheets("Models"))
wksModelsMenu.Name = StrSheetName
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct that the hard coded "2" may not be the new shape.  To over come this, after the add, I have:

    i=ws.shapes.count

and then use i as the index.

So far I have been able to add many shapes with this and it's working fine.

Comment: Ok. But the above is really the best way to address newly created objects. `Set myBar = foo.CreateBar()` is very often applicable in the Office object model. @LEBoyd