# 2010 Access - setting Excel hyperlink in a shape starts another Excel task

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a 2010 Access vba procedure that creates a workbook and adds sheets.  I then create a sheet (sheet1) that is a "menu" for the user the use for hyperlinking to the appropriate sheet.  The code looks like this:

```
with ws
    iLeft = 350
    iTop = 140
    iWidth = 160
    iHeight = 30
    .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight).Select
    i = wks.Shapes.Count
    .Shapes.Range(i).ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset33
    .Shapes.Range(i).TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
    .Shapes.Range(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "All Data"
    .Shapes.Range(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    .Shapes.Range(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8). _
        ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    With .Shapes.Range(i).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 8).Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
    Set HyperLinkShape = wks.Shapes(i)
    HyperSubAddress = "'All Data'!A1"
    .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=HyperLinkShape, Address:="", SubAddress:=HyperSubAddress
end with
```

There are hundreds of other lines of code, but I have narrowed down that the

```
.Hyperlinks.Add...
```

statement is causing a second occurrence of Excel to start.  Normally, that happens because I should be referencing the worksheet somewhere in the statement.  I tried:

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.HyperLinkShape, Address:="", SubAddress:=HyperSubAddress
```

and

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=HyperLinkShape, Address:="", SubAddress:=ws.HyperSubAddress
```

but both of these gave me a compiler error.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

Comment: I did additional testing and actually found that the "Set HyperLinkShape = wks.Shapes(i)" is what is causing the problem.  I will do research to see if I can figure that one out.

Comment: Again. Set object variables when you create objects. Don't use `.Select`. Don't mix `ws` and `wks`.

Comment: Thanks Andre.  The wks was a typo - good catch.

I'm not experienced enough to understand what you mean by setting object variables nor how to do the add without the .select.  Can you give me an example(s)?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, this was somewhat curt. I expanded on this topic in my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50231571/3820271 -- Do `Set HyperLinkShape = ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, iLeft, iTop, iWidth, iHeight)` and use that variable afterwards instead of `Shapes.Range(i)`. It may or may not solve the issue, but it is cleaner.

Comment: Andre, I changed the 'Shapes.Add...' to 'Set HyperLinkShape = ws.Shapes.AddShape...'

Tested to skip the 'Set' by jumping down just before to the close out and shut down the process.  Then I skipped just after the 'Set' line.  The first test worked but the second left the Excel process running.

I may have to change the process to set cells instead of adding nice shapes (:  

I just can't seem to get the hyperlink to set in a shape without causing Excel not to shut down properly.  (Or course, I haven't tested whether setting a hyperlink in a cell with Access vba will actually work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this.

The following standalone procedure runs in Access 2010. Both hyperlinks work.

After disposing of all objects (and `oExcel.Quit`), there is no more Excel process.
Note: you can do without all the `Set obj = Nothing`, then the Excel process closes after the procedure is finished, when all local variables go out of scope.

```
Public Sub TestExcelShapeHyperlink()

    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim shp As Excel.Shape

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With oExcel
        .UserControl = True
        .Visible = True
    End With

    Set wkb = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
    Set wks = wkb.ActiveSheet


    ' Note: there is no reason to select the shape
    Set shp = wks.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRoundedRectangle, 10, 10, 200, 100)
    ' Use the created object to set its properties
    With shp
        .ShapeStyle = msoShapeStylePreset10
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Bold = msoTrue
        .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "TEST TEST TEST"
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
        .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    End With

    ' Name 2nd sheet for hyperlink target
    wkb.Worksheets(2).Name = "All Data"

    ' Hyperlink 1 with anchor = shape
    wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shp, Address:="", SubAddress:="'All Data'!A1"

    ' Hyperlink 2 with anchor = a random cell
    wks.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=wks.Range("B11"), Address:="", SubAddress:="'All Data'!D5", TextToDisplay:="Click me, I'm a link!"

    Stop        ' 1 Excel process

    Set shp = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing

    wkb.SaveAs "D:\foo.xlsx"
    wkb.Close
    Set wkb = Nothing

    oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing

    Stop        ' 0 Excel processes

End Sub
```

Comment: And therein lies my stupidity...  I looked and your code and immediately realized I had forgotten to set the shape to nothing before finishing.  Doht!!!  Thank you so much for your patience and help.